# USBPrivateDataSample on Mac Snow Leopard

Tags: xcode, usb, core-foundation, iokit

I need to create application that get notified each time I plug or unplug USB, and also can get access to it. For start, I tried to use USBPrivateDataSample application as example:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/USBPrivateDataSample/Listings/USBPrivateDataSample_c.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000456-USBPrivateDataSample_c-DontLinkElementID_4

In order to compile it I changed SDK to 10.6 since 10.4 is not supported on Snow Leopard.
The program is compiled and runs successfully, however, I do not receive calls/events when the USB is plugged in. In other words, function DeviceAdded is never called.

Does this program supposed to work in Snow anyway? It looks old, maybe some calls are deprecated?

Can someone suggest other way to receive USB devices notifications?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you did change `kMyVendorID` and `kMyProductID` to match your device, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The sample should work on 10.6, You may need to modify the matching dictionary to either match all devices by removing the `kUSBProductID` and `kUSBVendorID` matching dictionary entries, or set these to match your device, you can also use different matching criteria (see [qa1076](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1076/_index.html) for those).

Comment: Thank you very much!! It really help! I thought that the device filtering is done actually inside the DeviceAdded function.

Comment: @Iron-Eagle: Happy to help, if this question does help you, you may upvote it or accept it, see [faq#howtoask]

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. Now I need to get product ID and Vendor ID from connected USB device - what is the best way to do it?

In addition I need to get path for the device in order to read file from it - how can I do that?

Comment: @Iron-Eagle: since you now have an IOUSBDeviceInterface object, you can use `GetDeviceProduct` and `GetDeviceVendor`. see the [IOUSBDeviceInterface documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/IOKit/IOUSBLib_h/Classes/IOUSBDeviceInterface/index.html)

Comment: Yeah, I figured out this part already, thanks! But what about reading file from USB? How do I access it now?

Comment: @Iron-Eagle: You mean, accessing a file from a Mass Storage device? I don't have an immediate answer, but you may want to ask this as a separate question, since it's somewhat off-topic

Comment: Well, maybe meanwhile you can explain me this: Suppose I have a call - CFNumberGetValue((CFNumberRef)val, kCFNumberCharType, (void*)&fManufacturerStringIndex); - What is ManufacturerStringINDEX?? And how can I get the string itself? Thanks!

Comment: @Iron-Eagle: It's the index of the manufacturer string from the device descriptor, `IOUSBDevice` has a `GetStringDescriptor` method, which isn't exported. You can either use the source for that one, or simply get the device's `USB Vendor Name` property, which contains the string you need.